# Is there a standard framework for maintaining a persistent connection to a REST API with a token that times out?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that I am writing, that will act as a middle layer between an internal vendor application, and a few things we want exposed publicly.

This internal application issues api tokens in response to a login request, and they expire with a hard limit of 4 hours.

For reasons I cannot change, this vendor login process can take up to 10 seconds, too long to do it live when user refreshes the page after 4 hours.

Neither of those times can be changed as it is a vendor application doing very specific business processes, and we can file a request to them, but cannot expect anything in the time frame I need to get my external application running in.

The obvious option is to have some process that runs every 3 hours or so, and refreshes the token, out of band.

I'm hoping to find out if there is an existing framework for this sort of thing, in spring or something else, so I dont end up reinventing the wheel.

Edit: adding this info because it is too long to fit int he comment:

Part of why I wanted to check if there was already a standard way to do this, or a best practice from someone reliable, is two things.
I know that OAuth2 tokens can have an expiration time and a refresh token, and it seems like someone may have made a framework for doing that renewal asynchronously, so that on the next user request to the application they don't necessarily have to wait for the renewal.

So if there is a most common or recommended way to handle those OAuth2 token renewals, the menhod of doing it would probably apply to me.  Wether that is to do it in some asynchronous way, or to just do it on the users next intentional request.

Also, when I was writing up the question, I was thinking a little about how the database drivers maintain a persistent connection in an application server like WebSphere. I admit I don't know for sure that they actually do, but it seems to me like many of them would probably try to take care of relogin behind the scenes.  If that's not true I'm happy to hear it.

Edit 2:

The primary goal of what I want, is I don't want my users to have to wait for the very slow login to this internal application when they are viewing my web page, but I do want to get them access to the data in it.

I login to the internal application with a system/application ID, separate from any of my user accounts, so there's nothing requiring me to wait until a user requests data from it, other than the fact that I don't have much experience with java standard or springs enhanced Executor Services.

so the details of the frameworks or best practices, would probably be proper use of Java/Spring Executor Service, or other asynchronous process manager, that I can spawn off these refresh threads, and properly handle their response codes and/or exceptions.

Comment: I think you have quite an exotic use case there, wouldn't really expect a "wheel" for it to exist. Also, I'm not really sure what you would expect as an answer. A software library? A standard? A mechanism explained?

Comment: Please don't get me wrong but this sounds like a major code smell. After working on several projects with legacy systems, my experience says that its best to take a step back now and refactor the spaghetti code instead of adding more stuff on top of it. Sooner or later, business prioritizes code clean when everything's on fire. In most cases, its too late by then.

Comment: @22kar, I suppose I misspoke when I said legacy, it is a third part application we are integrating, that we cannot change, and it has a good reason for the login to take that long.  It doesn't have a good reason to timeout these logins, but I still am not able to change it :-)

Comment: @eis I have updated the question with some comments, basically around how I know OAuth2 has an expiration date and renewal token, and if there is any gold standard way of handling that from a user perspective, and some other things.

Comment: "Framework" sounds like hell of a big word for creating a timer in Spring and calling the thing to log in every 3 hours.

Comment: @jingx and all It has been a while since my last comment, since I am just doing it manually, but I have some more comments about why 'just a timer' may not work. One thing that can happen with the server is that it invalidates cookies on reboot, or other things, in which case the 3 hour timer will not catch.  Then if I get a bulk request that I have to forward to the server - 1 request to me, say 50 to the server - I have to catch the 401 error the first time it is seen, and pause my thread pool I am using to send these individual requests. This feature was not mentioned in my question.